# Windows 7 Desktop background picture in Group Policy displaying black - XP working correctly

Tags: background

We want everyone on the Windows Domain to have the same desktop background. This is set up in a Group Policy. This works great in Windows XP but the Windows 7 machines display a black background.

I have re-created the Group Policy, done various tests with different types and sizes of files Enabling and Disabling Active Desktop. I have researched and tried some options and patches from Microsoft as well.

Any idea what I can try or even how to determine the problem?

Comment: What does RSoP say about your Win7 machines?

Comment: RSoP does display the correct details for the Desktop Wallpaper Policy.

Answer (score 2):

Known issue, however this should have been resolved in SP1:

**The "Desktop Wallpaper" Group Policy setting is not applied in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977944

https://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/11/20/windows-7-rtm-issue-with-group-policy-enforced-wallpaper.aspx

Comment: I have created the Registry item in a test Group Policy and asked the on-site technician to test.

Comment: Test not working. If I manually enter the registry details I still get a black background.

Comment: Running more tests on a test machine.